# Insert data concurrently, whereas the new row should be computed based on last inserted row

Tags: database, postgresql, concurrency, aws-lambda, isolation-level

I am working on a system which gives points to users based on the amount they spent on transaction

Whenever the customer performs transaction an message will be pushed to sqs and triggers a lambda (.net core , Ef core, postgresql) which checks whether the points are present in the points table for that customer, if yes it calculates new point based on the last received points and inserts another row because we need to maintain the points history. However, when the user performs multiple transactions concurrently, the points is not calculated properly.

Points table

Userid pointsbefore pointsafter pointsreceived  transactionid
    1       0            10           10             1
    1       10           20           10             2 
    1       20           30           10             3 
    1       20           30           10             4

Transaction id 3&4 -> occured concurrently.

I tried various isolation levels such as read commited and serializable. But not working.

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue.

Comment: You example has some formatting issues which make it incomprehensible.  Can you reformat it?

Answer (score 0):

If you use serializable isolation level, then one transaction will get a serialization error when the system detects the anomaly, and will have to be rolled back and retried.

Or you can just have the coding rule in the app that anyone planning on potentially inserting a points records must lock the customer record ("SELECT...FOR UPDATE") before reading or inserting the points.